# Modify PDF document to display image on mouse over text using Python or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, pdf

I have a PDF document in which I need to add a mouse over event on a particular text such that it displays a image when user hovers over that text and hides it on mouse exit. I can use Python or Javascript to achieve this. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/